# Is there a way to tell in linux if a binary program that is running matches file on the disk?

Tags: linux

Suppose a binary executable program is running:

For example:
ps -eaf | grep someServer

shows that someServer is running.

Is it possible to tell if someServer executable on disk ( eg /usr/bin/someServer ) matches the program that was actually started ?

Comment: meaning you want to know if the file has been changed since it was started,  or which exact version of a command was run,  `/usr/bin/someServer` vs `/home/user/someServer`?

Comment: Since executables are loaded by memory mapping, and Linux has a unified VM/cache system, I see hardly a way it could be any different (leaving relocation and self-modifying code out of consideration). Of course you can "secretly overwrite" an executable file while it's loaded by replacing its _link_, but the underlying file remains the same.

Comment: Yes I am looking to find exact version that was started.  The reason is I am seeing some strange NFS caching issues where I build a server, copy it to the bin directory, and then start the server ( from another machine ) and then the server starts but it looks like it is running the old version.  I want to confirm that it is infact runnning the old version and that I'm not going insane.

Answer (score 10):

Yes: Use soft link `/proc/$pid/exe` to get the path which was used to load the code.

Look into `/proc/$pid/maps`. It will look like this (for `/sbin/getty`):

```
00400000-00407000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 3145779                            /sbin/getty
00606000-00607000 r--p 00006000 08:01 3145779                            /sbin/getty
00607000-00608000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 3145779                            /sbin/getty
... lots more ...
```

Filter the file using the path that you got from the soft link to find the lines that are interesting for you.

The last number (`3145779`) is the inode of the file. When you create a new file on disk, it gets a new inode.

To see the inode of a file, use `ls --inode /sbin/getty`:

```
3145779 /sbin/getty
```

Since the two numbers are still identical, the executable on disk is the same as in RAM.

Background: Linux doesn't load processes into RAM at once. Instead, the executable file is memory-mapped into RAM using the virtual memory subsystem. This means parts of the executable which you never use will never be loaded into memory. It also means that the kernel uses the executable on disk as a "cache".

When you overwrite the executable on disk, the original inode is not changed. Your existing process hangs on to it. Instead, a new inode is created and the directory node (which contains the file name and a pointer to the inode with the data) is updated. This is why you can overwrite files that are currently in use on Linux.

The original inode will be cleaned up when the last process which uses it dies.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you mean exactly.

- use pid matching (compare ps output and getpid() in the server)
- use /proc/$pid/environ and find _=path_to_someServer (there is the binary)
- use **diff /proc/$pid/exe someServer** ("type someServer" to get full path)

Comment: The 3rd option is I believe what I'm looking for.

Comment: Suppose I run ./someServer in background. And then overwrite binary with new different file ./someServer.  Now the server that was started is different than one on disk.  Is it possible to tell that this overwrite occurred?

Comment: I've checked and it works. Notice I corrected my initial answer. Overrite usually is not allowed if process is started as root.

Comment: @nopsoft: But `rm` is allowed. Also, the running program is not necessarily loaded from the disk in full, there is a concept of paging so that only some parts of the program might be loaded AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if any running processes were spawned from a particular executable inode:

```
# find -L /proc/[0-9]*/exe -samefile /usr/bin/someServer
```

This command will output a list of `/proc/<pid>/exe` pathnames, one for each process whose executable image was mapped into memory from the same inode as is presently linked at `/usr/bin/someServer`.

Note that the command will **NOT** find processes that were spawned from inodes that were *formerly* linked at `/usr/bin/someServer` but have since been unlinked, such as if a newer version of the executable has replaced a running version.